# Compiler error - msgfmt command not found

Tags: git, compiler-errors, gettext, shared-hosting, msgfmt

I'm trying to update Git from my shared hosting. For that I'm following these steps:

1. Download latest Git version
2. Unpack and place it on the server
3. Configure and create the Makefile -> `./configure --prefix=$HOME/dev/git/src --without-tcltk`
4. Build the package -> `make` then `make install`
5. Update PATH .bash_profile

I'm stuck at point 4. When I run the `make` command, I get the following:

```
user@ssh1:~/dev/git/src$ make
SUBDIR gitweb
SUBDIR ../
make[2]: ? GIT-VERSION-FILE ? est ? jour.
GEN git-instaweb
SUBDIR perl
SUBDIR git_remote_helpers
SUBDIR templates
MSGFMT po/build/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
/bin/sh: msgfmt: command not found
make: *** [po/build/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo] Erreur 127
```

Compiler throws a `msgfmt command not found` error.

I Googled it and it seems to be related to the gettext package.

Any idea how to fix that error on a shared hosting?

Comment: Quick hack: try "make -k" or "make -i" to skip compiling this, may be you will get Git, but without localization and/or documents.

Comment: You're right msgfmt is not vital to run Git.
"make -i" worked thanks.

Comment: For OSX you can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32821791/1257959

Answer (score 291):

I had the same issue. Thanks to your work on finding it was related to gettext, a simple `apt-get install gettext` fixed it for me.

Comment: This should be acceped answer ;)

Comment: This certainly seems like the best answer, however, on cygwin, installing gettext did not help.  Perhaps a version issue there?

Comment: This is not the right answer on shared hosting, where you don't have sudo access.

Comment: @Lucas on cygwin you need gettext-devel for msgfmt (see [this helpful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22159893/602119))

Comment: When installing from source/on a system without root access, run `./configure && make && make install` in the `gettext-tools` subdirectory below the `gettext` source root.

Comment: Thank you! Me: in centos: yum install gettext

Comment: how do i install it in windows 10? I didn't find any reliable guide for windows setup of  gettext.

Answer (score 19):

While building Git with Xcode (using Makefile), I had to define `NO_GETTEXT = YesPlease` in the Makefile to resolve this issue.

Comment: Preferred this, as I couldn’t install gettext, and -i (ignore errors) is just daft! `make NO_GETTEXT=1` did the trick.

Answer (score 18):

`msgfmt` is included in the `gettext-devel` cygwin package. Install that (via setup.exe or `apt-cyg`) and the error should go away.

Comment: The question is not about Cygwin

Comment: gettext-devel is also the package for centos 6

Answer (score 8):

On Mac Os, this worked for me:

```
brew install gettext
```

```
brew link gettext --force
```

Answer (score 4):

```
make -i
make -i install
```

..worked flawlessy for this problem. Also if anyone's having trouble with http/https helper, during configure do not forget to add the following thing

```
./configure --with-curl --with-expat
```

Comment: It should be noted that "-i" is short for "--ignore-errors", so any other error will be ignored too and may be overlooked because of the many gettext-related errors. So -i should be the last resort if nothing else works.

Comment: @Boris Yes, it's a wrong work-around, but not everyone's a hacker. You obviously need gettext lib for the error to go.

Answer (score 4):

On cygwin, you need to install the gettext-devel package as well. The gettext package alone is not enough to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can install gettext in the same way you are installing git. By downloading, extracting, building and installing it to a given location in your home folder:

```
curl -O https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gettext/gettext-0.20.1.tar.gz
tar xvf gettext-0.20.1.tar.gz
cd gettext-0.20.1/
./configure --prefix=/home/$HOME/opt
make
make install
```

Set the prefix to the location you want for the installation.

Answer (score 2):

In Debian 10 to me was missing package `gettext`. Solved as follow:

`$ sudo apt install gettext`

Then `make` commando worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

**`xgettext`**, **`msgfmt`** and etc. belong to GNU `gettext` toolset. On **macOS**, you could use [MacPort](https://macports.org)'s `port` command to install these tools on your system:

```
port install gettext
```

Answer (score 0):

There's one more option to obtain the software:

```
ipkg install gettext
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add **-i** to your make command.

`> make -i ...`