# pygettext.py and msgfmt.py on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, localization, gettext

I want to translate strings in my Python app on my Mac OS X 10.7.
I can import the `gettext` module but i can't find the tools `pygettext.py` and `msgfmt.py`, which according to the Python docs should be somewhere in my Python installation.

Is the pre-installed Python version on Mac OS X 10.7 missing these tools and if yes, how can I get them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both of those scripts reside in the miscellaneous Tools directory of the Python source.  This directory is often not included in a binary installation of Python such as the ones supplied by Apple in OS X.  However, it is easy to download them separately from a Python source release; see the most recent releases [here](http://www.python.org/download/).  For the current Python 2.7.3 release, you could do the following:

```
$ curl -O http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tgz
$ tar -xf Python-2.7.3.tgz 
$ cd Python-2.7.3
$ cd Tools/i18n/
$ ls
makelocalealias.py  msgfmt.py*          pygettext.py*
```

Beginning with Python 3.2, the `Tools` directory is installed by python.org OS X binary installers.  You'll find it inside the Python framework at:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/share/doc/python3.2/examples/Tools
```

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the Tools separately.

Comment: on Mac 10.8.5 curl did not work for me, but `wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tgz` did the trick

Comment: no reason `curl` shouldn't work, @jrgray.  You might need `-L` in case the URL does a redirect to the actual location of the file you're dowloading.

Answer (score 14):

With python 3 and MacOS >= 10.9, installing `gettext` via homebrew won't link the libraries and this will produce the error `Can't find msgfmt`.

This helps:

```
$ brew install gettext  # if not already done
$ brew link gettext --force
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785138/621690

Answer (score 1):

create a symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/share/doc/python3.7/examples/Tools/i18n/pygettext.py /usr/local/bin/pygettext
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python correctly installed in Linux you should be able to access the binary versions from the command line. So, to make the .pot file, you can type:

```
    $> pygettext [options] source_file_list
```

I found I had two versions of pygettext, one for 2.7, and another for 3.2, but they seem to work pretty much the same. To create the .mo files from the .po files:

```
    $> msgfmt [options] file.po
```

but you need to make sure you do not accidentally use the gnu version. The Python version of msgfmt is much simpler. Both commands have help, so you can check the options (and versions) with:

```
    $> pygettext --help
```

and

```
    $> msgfmt --help
```

If in doubt, downloading the Python source as suggested above is the belt-and-braces approach.

I am still finding my way round i18n myself, so if someone knows better, please add your comments :)

Answer (score 0):

By using `find . -name pygettext.py/msgfmt.py`, I can't find these two files on macOS, no mater in system python installation (`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions`) or in Anaconda Python distribution.

But we can always directly download these two files from the Python source code. At this time, they located in: https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Tools/i18n

---

Besides, `pygettext.py` and `msgfmt.py` are the mimics of GNU `gettext` toolset: **`xgettext`** and **`msgfmt`**. You can also check whether or not these GNU toolset have already been installed. (`type -a xgettext/msgfmt`)

If not, you can install then by using either [MacPort](https://macports.org)'s `port` command or [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/)'s `conda` command.

```
port install gettext
conda install gettext
```