# What are the downsides to using the official Windows Git binaries from cygwin?

Tags: git, svn, cygwin, git-svn

Cygwin's latest git, svn and git-svn combination is stuck at old versions that have [numerous](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-08/msg00206.html) git-svn [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693255/git-svn-dcommit-fails-because-of-assertion-error-svn-fspath-is-canonicalchild?rq=1).  I'm considering just downloading the official windows version (warning: this will start the a download: http://git-scm.com/download/win ), putting that in my path, and calling those binaries from Cygwin.  What are the downsides to this?

Comment: The downvoters (and the close voter) probably felt that "What are the downsides" is too broad. I see their point, but I don't necessarily agree; there are a couple of very specific disadvantages that I can think of. (Arguably the question is too broad but the answer isn't -- or something like that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-Cygwin Windows binaries won't be able to see Cygwin-style file paths. For example, your home directory might be `/home/yourname` as seen from Cygwin, but `C:\cygwin\home\yourname` as seen from Windows. Interactions between a Windows installation of `git` and the Unix-like Cygwin toolkit are likely to be very tricky.

Line endings may also be an issue.

An alternative is to build `git` from source.

Comment: After asking, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20081611/61624  I may be able to use this.

Answer (score 2):

The official binary is [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.io/) (it says so on the download page).

The Git for Windows binary doesn't work very well with some cygwin tools.

For me, that means it doesn't work with mintty:

- [No colors when running native windows shell application from mintty](https://superuser.com/questions/184186/no-colors-when-running-native-windows-shell-application-from-mintty)
- [support for native console programs](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56)

git doesn't page or color output because it doesn't understand how to speak mintty's language.

I think the biggest problem is that I want to use cygwin as a complete suite of unix tools, but I get the impression that the goal of Git for Windows it to make Git a native Windows tool:

> Finally, I came to the conclusion that it's too hard to make mintty work 
>   with msysgit. And IMHO, using mintty (although it's a great terminal) 
>   also is a step in the wrong direction in the sense that it introduces 
>   further tools and dependencies that are not Windows-native.
>   [Sebastian Schuberth (msysgit contributor)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/eAgLeDsbYzI)

It's a noble goal, but it doesn't meet my needs. Your mileage may vary.

Anecdotal: I haven't noticed problems with paths or line endings. However, Cygwin now provides [git-2.1.1-1](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Fgit%2Fgit-2.1.1-1&grep=git) so I'm giving up on msysgit.