# How do I build and use the latest version of git on cygwin?

Tags: git, cygwin

As for why I'd want to do this, see this question: [What are the downsides to using the official Windows Git binaries from cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027917/what-are-the-downsides-to-using-the-official-windows-git-binaries-from-cygwin)

Or you could look at this: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Fwd-Error-with-git-svn-pushing-a-rename-td7599382.html  It prevents you from pushing renamed files to the svn server.

Cygwin is stuck at a version of git that has numerous bugs when used with the git-svn bridge.  A lot of these have been fixed in the latest git (their master branch, not the one available for download).  So how do you get, build and use it?

I'll answer this below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Git 1.8 in Cygwin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330050/how-to-get-git-1-8-in-cygwin)

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14330050/79125 (which is out of date -- probably better to give it an update answer and edit the title than to create a new question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To compile git, you're going to need to install a few required packages.  I'm going to assume you know how to install things on cygwin by using their setup.exe.  Here's what you need to install:

```
git (you need git to get git source)
make
gcc-core
libcurl-devel
openssl-devel
subversion-perl
dos2unix
libiconv
libiconv-devel
gettext
expat
gettext-devel
expat-devel
```

Here's how you get the source:

```
git clone https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/git/git.git
cd git
```

Now for some reason I don't understand, I have to convert all the files to have unix line endings.  I don't understand why they didn't already come that way.  I did that with this:

```
find . -type f | xargs dos2unix
```

Finally I did these steps:

```
  make -j8
  make test; # optional, to verify that the git you built works ok
  export PATH=$(pwd)/bin-wrappers:$PATH
```

The git binaries are in `./bin-wrappers`.  You probably want to permanently add that directory to your path.

Comment: Hmm, when I did it there were no changes after converting dos2unix, so that step is probably not needed.

Comment: I needed libiconv-devel as well.  Not sure if libiconv is required.

Comment: I also needed to follow instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330050/how-to-get-git-1-8-in-cygwin/18604066#18604066 due to a problem with the version of msgfmt that cygwin comes with.

Comment: @jmh odd, I definitely didn't have to do the steps linked in that answer.  Re: libiconv-devel, I'll take your word for it.  This was about an hour of trial and error so I may have missed that.  I'm going to leave libiconv in just in case.

Comment: Well I am on windows 7 64 bit.  Maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: I assume the need of dos2unix or not dependes on the setting `git config core.autocrlf`. If it is true, you need to convert the line endings (back) to unix.

Comment: There have been some changes since this was posted. `openssl-devel` is now `libssl-devel`, and `expat-devel` is `libexpat-devel`.

Answer (score 1):

Also needed to add zlib-devel at least for git 2.25