# Once I compile and install chosen version of git, how do I force the shared hosting to use my version?

Tags: linux, git, github, cpanel, shared-hosting

Continuing from [Compiler error - msgfmt command not found when compiling git on a shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500898/compiler-error-msgfmt-command-not-found-when-compiling-git-on-a-shared-hosting/)

How do I, after managing to make and install the latest git, force the cpanel shared host to use my version?

- My version is under `/home/<ME>/git/git-2.9.0`
- I compiled the make script with

  ```
  make -i prefix=/home/<ME>/bin all
  ```
- `echo $PATH;` lists that path in the variable. Also, the path is *appended* to the current PATH.

Now, I want the server to respond with

```
/home/<ME>/bin/git
```

when I run `which git`

Comment: Run `echo $PATH` and tell us what it says.

Comment: @JohnZwinck -  Like I said, the path seems to be appended alright---the output of echoing the path variable is `home/<me>/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin:/home/<me>/bin`

Comment: Is the PATH lookup recursive? - Does the host lookup for a binary in any/all nested sub directories?

Comment: It is not recursive.  But the more important thing is that you've put your preferred path at the END when it should be at the START of the $PATH variable.  As it stands, your system will only look in your directory as a last resort, after all the other ones where it might find `git`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO,Post Installation, the binaries were stored in

> `/home/<ME>/bin/bin/`

because, I compiled with

`make -i prefix=/home/<ME>/bin all`

## Issue

PATH lookups are not recursive.

## SOLUTION

- Optionally, Move all git binaries into a sub directory under `/home/<me>/bin/`
- Just add all subdirectories of `/home/<ME>/bin/`

to the current PATH. inside `.~/.bash_profile`

and do

`source ~/.bash_profile`